# Launching an Applicatiion from an Iphone browser

Tags: iphone, browser, add-on

Is it possible to doe one of the following?

A/ (the preference) Launch an application on the iPhone from either the native browser of the recently released Opera browser?

B/ Have a 'addon' or other 'module' for a either of the two iPhone browsers that acts like an application?

Comment: What does B mean? There are thousands of web apps that are applications that run in the browser. There are also specialized iPhone browsers other than Safari and Opera that add additional functionality on top of the UIWebKit stuff.

Comment: I found out that what I was looking for was something like Titaniaum and Phonegap. Someone makes a web app and it runs basically in an enhanced, chrome less browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a [URL scheme](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW26) for your application and embed said URL as a link on a website that can be clicked through any iPhone browser.

[Here's a quick guide](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)